# .NET Application crashes silent only when a debugger is attached. How do I locate the faulting code?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, debugging

I have an .NET application which crashes when I attach a debugger. Without an attached debugger it runs as expected.

When the application crashes it just vanishes and no error message is displayed anywhere.
Visual studio which I used to start the  application and attach the debugger is still running but it did recognize that the debugger isn't running anymore.

The behavior doesn't happen every time but it is quite reliable.

---

How can I analyze this error?

---

This is what the `Event Viewer` tells me:

```
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.86, time stamp: 0x3fee4d7f
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x001133d2
Faulting process id: 0xf7f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d59df4ddb019b5
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a24c3846-a339-43ae-a3fb-04665b1b76a4
```

---

What have I tried:

- I've eddited the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps` registry key to automaticly create a crash dump but nothing is beeing created
- I've set the following debugg options to true

  - "Break all processes when one process breaks"
  - "Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries (Managed only)
  - "Use the new Exception Helper"
- As it is an `WPF` Application I subscribe to the `DispatcherUnhandledException` event but it isn't published
- A simple try catch in the `static void Main()` method but the code in the `catch` isn't hit
- Under `Debug > Windows > Exception Settings` I've enabled all `C++ Exceptions`, `Managed Debugging Assistants` and `Win32 Exceptions`

---

I'm using the following products:

- Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.0.3
- Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.16
- .NET 4.6.1
- Windows 10 Version 1903

---

Project specialties:

- I have some special STA theads extra for COM and they can be blocking for a while which shouldn't be bad as they are background threads.

---

*Basicly my question isn't why is this code not working but how can I find the code which is not working.*

Comment: Which code causes this problem? Btw, how do you attach a debugger, just run in debug mode or something else?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Well it is a huge project and therefore I can't tell. That is what I try to get the answer to. I can imagine it could be because of some COM threads but in my opinion it would not make sense to add code parts which could be the problem but in the end aren't. There is simply to much code. I can also imagine that some native code which is called by PInvoke just kills the thread it is running on and therefore the .net application crashes.

Comment: It can happen, if somewhere in your code `Enviroment.FailFast()` method is called. Which debugger are you trying to attach and how, just run app in debug mode or something else?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes I just click the run in debug mode button in visual studio and I do not call `Enviroment.FailFast` anywhere.

Comment: What does call stack say?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I do not get an exception and therefore no call stack. It's like the operating system decided to shutdown the runtime or the runtime itself crashes.

Comment: are you using any 3rd party DLLs or SDKs?

Comment: @BossRoss Yes some nuget packages some com interop libraries and some PInvoke calls.

Comment: Creating a crash dump would be most useful. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I'm using Windows 10 Version 1903.